# Prevent Graphiql console from issuing multiple introspection queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphiql

I am using the `Graphiql` component to render a console and want to fetch the schema via an introspection query. The problem is that if the component re-renders before the first introspection query is resolved (say a modal is opened for example), a second introspection query is fired off. Given that these queries are expensive for the backend, I'd like to avoid this.

Is there a way to avoid multiple introspection queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphiQL component accepts a `schema` prop:

> `schema`: a GraphQLSchema instance or `null` if one is not to be used. If `undefined` is provided, GraphiQL will send an introspection query using the fetcher to produce a schema.

You can use `getIntrospectionQuery` to get the complete introspection schema, fetch the introspection result and then use it to build a schema.

```
const { getIntrospectionQuery, buildClientSchema } = require('graphql')

const response = await fetch('ENDPOINT_URL', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: { query: JSON.stringify(getIntrospectionQuery()) },
})
const introspectionResult = await response.json()
const schema = buildClientSchema(introspectionResult.data)
```

Do this before you render the component and then just pass in the schema as a prop. If your schema isn't going to change, you can also just save the introspection result to a file and use that instead of querying the server.

Comment: I works! I made two minor changes to get it working. Once those changes are approved I can approve this answer. Thanks so much!